# How to delete a scheme in CocoaPods post_install hook

Tags: cocoapods

How does one delete a scheme created by CocoaPods in the `post_install` hook? It is a little convoluted, but this scheme is [breaking Carthage builds](https://github.com/SwiftKickMobile/SwiftMessages/issues/465) for my SwiftMessages library.

According to [this thread](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj/issues/708), deleting schemes is possible. However, I've looked through the [CocoaPods reference](https://rubydoc.info/gems/cocoapods/Pod/Project) and don't see a way to do it.

### Update

Following Thiago Cruz's suggestion, I added the following post install hook to my project. Keeping it simple, I just blew away all of the user and shared data in the pods project.

```rb
post_install do |installer|
  # Blow away schemes – the schemes created by CocoaPods break Carthage builds
  # because they incluede a SwiftMessages framework that Carthage picks
  # over the main SwiftMessages framework. The SwiftMessages framework that gets
  # picked is configured for an app extension and doesn't work correctly in an app.
  File.directory?(path)
  [
    "#{installer.sandbox.root}/Pods.xcodeproj/xcuserdata",
    "#{installer.sandbox.root}/Pods.xcodeproj/xcshareddata"
  ].each { |path|
    if File.directory?(path)
      FileUtils.remove_dir(path)
    end
  }
end
```

In addition to this, I had to open the pods project and disable "Autocreate schemes" in the scheme management dialog. It's worth noting that `pod install` doesn't revert this setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure which `.xcscheme` files you want to delete but in a `post_install` hook you have access to the root of your project and also the `/Pods` root. You could `glob` your way to the file and manually delete it.

```
post_install do |installer|
  puts "#{installer.config.installation_root}"
  puts "#{installer.sandbox.root}"
end
```